# css file can't be loaded with spring boot

Tags: java, html, css, spring, spring-boot

following is my file dir tree, and html files is in src/main/webapp/templates, have added src/main/webapp into classpath.

```
src──main
     ├─java
     │  └─com
     │      └─ma2oo
     │          └─quizbox
     │              ├─application
     │              ├─config
     │              └─controllers
     ├─resources
     └─webapp
         ├─static
         │  ├─css
         │  └─js
         └─templates
```

The web config file is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        System.out.println("reached here ");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor);
    }
}
```

And the ref link in html is:

```
  <link href="/static/css/components.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
```

When web server is running, I can't get the expected result from browser, it's just same with there is no css existed.

Could anyone help with it please? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using Spring Boot, it is not the best idea to have the resources in under `webapp`. See this part of [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content) official Spring Boot documentation

I propose you move all the static content you now have under `/webapp` to `/resources` and also get rid of the `addResourceHandlers` configuration method since Spring boot will automatically map the static content correctly.

Then for example you would have `<link href="css/components.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>`

For a sample spring boot project that uses static content, check out [this](http://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot).

Comment: it works as you said, very thanks for saving my day.

Comment: I have my js file in `src/main/resources/js/custom-js.js`, and reference it like `src="js/custom-js.js` but this doesn't work...

Comment: Did you check out the link to the sample project?

Answer (score 1):

If you have annotated your controller class, or one of your methods in your controller class, with `@RequestMapping("/")` remove the annotation and try it.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you're using to reference the CSS file does not match the path pattern you registered in your resource handler. You need to use a link such as the following instead:

`<link href="/resources/css/components.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>`

(Note that by default Spring Boot registers a handler for resources in the webapp root. However, by using the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation, you are overriding that default behavior. If you remove that annotation, then your existing HTML link would work as is.)

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't work when I replace the corresponding line to `<link href="/resources/css/components.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>` and removed the `@EnableWebMvc`

Comment: You should only perform one of those actions. As you discovered, performing both at the same time doesn't improve the situation.

Comment: Sorry for unclear, I tried these two methods one by one, but none worked, thank you all the same.